# How to properly set sessions in HttpContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I am using:

```
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myHttpContext.Request.QueryString["code"]))
    {

        if (myHttpContext.Session == null || myHttpContext.Session["code"] == null)
        {
            OutputError("Code", "Invalid code.");
        }
        else
        {
            code = myHttpContext.Session["code"].ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        code = myHttpContext.Request.QueryString["code"];
        myHttpContext.Session.Add("code", code);
    }
```

However I keep getting the error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

For:
myHttpContext.Session.Add("code", code);

All I want to do is set a simple session, someone please help this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has your IHttpHandler (ashx) class implemented [IRequireSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx)? Otherwise the Session object will not be accessible.

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequireSessionState
{
   public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx)
   {
       // your code here
   }
}
```

Comment: Years later, this was the first post I found that gave this solution. It needs more upvotes. :) In my case the interface I used was `System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `if (myHttpContext != null)`

However you might want to use the always-present context instead: `HttpContext.Current`

```
// if querystring parameter has a value
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["code"]))
    // then use its value
```

---

Same for Session (if it's present - see @davisleeps answer for that) 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8598088/179972

Comment: All I have is CurrentHandler and CurrentNotification.

Comment: That is working fine. I cannot believe I can't do simple sessions with this, I am going to have to use cookies.

Comment: Those aren't in your original question, but check them for null also, if you're unsure. You can update your question to provide more information and more code if you think it's relevant to the problem.

Comment: I was just going to look up information about how to enable the session but @davidsleeps just got to it first, so I upvoted his answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8598088/179972

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might want to try

```
myHttpContext.Session["code"] = code;
```